# How to read the displayed value of a spreadsheet cell, not the formula?

Tags: python, excel, win32com, openoffice-calc

I have a program that reads the value of a cell in a spreadsheet (via COM) by accessing its 'Text' member. When I was using Excel 2003, my program correctly returned the displayed value of the cell. Now I am using OpenOffice Calc, and instead I am getting back the formula in the cell ('=SUM(F8:F10)').

To complicate matters, I am using a tool called [AutomateIT!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automateit/) to let me treat Calc as if it was Excel, so it might be that that's causing the problem instead of Calc.

My program is in Python, and I use the win32com.client library to create the COM dispatcher. 
This is the essence of the Python code (the 'empty' function always returns false for a cell containing a formula):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def empty(cell):
    """Returns false if the specified cell has a non-zero value in it"""
    val = sheet.Range(cell).Text
    return val == 0.0 or val == '' or val == None

xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application')   # Actually opens OpenOffice Calc, thanks to AutomateIT!

xlApp.Workbooks.Open('myfile.ods')

sheet = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)

if empty('F12'):
    sheet.Range('C2').Value = 'X'   # Never get here because F12 is a formula cell

...
```

Using 'Value' in empty() gives the same value as 'Text'.

Comment: Mercy, that's a lot of technology, just to get a value from a spreasheet.

Comment: When you switched to OpenOffice Calc did you start using ods files or did you stick with xls/xlsx?

Comment: Initially I was just using Python/win32com to open Excel. Now that my employer has decided to move to OpenOffice, I no longer have Excel. AutomateIT! should make Calc look like Excel, so I thought I'd give that a try. And it mostly works, except for reading the value of formula cells.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the file saved as a CVS in Excel and then use the csv module to pull the data from the file? That will give you the data of the cell rather than the formula.

Comment: I would imagine that he wants to keep the formulas.

Comment: My fallback position is to open the file by hand and edit it. However, I used to be able to run a Python script to do the mod I wanted, and I'd like to keep doing that if it's at all possible.